# Android ionic Framework app Hangs in Samsung S5

Tags: android, ionic-framework, galaxy, s5

I had made an android application using ionic framework. My app works fine on all devices except on a Samsung Galaxy S5. When I try to run my app on a  S5 the app hangs a lot and crashes at several points. I did a lot of R&D on Google but didn't find any solution. Can anyone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: Looks like others have encountered this issue, too. You might want to include code that causes problems for you in your post. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1729

Comment: This is the point i didn't understand that which one code is raising this problem because my app contains a lot of code and i didn't understand the exact loop hole this is becoming the main cause of hang.

Comment: I haven't worked with Android much, but to debug your code, you will probably want to throw some breakpoints in to see where your code is crashing, what happens leading up to the crash, etc.